# EOFException in java networking

Tags: java, networking, eofexception

it is my first time using java networking. I have to use it for a project i am working on which is a simple card game. My server and client will communicate as the "Connection Received" does get printed. But after this line the following error occurs:

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at ClientConnectionManager.reciveData(ClientConnectionManager.java:49)
at LogicThread.getHandSize(GameLogic.java:22)
at LogicThread.run(GameLogic.java:16)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.NullPointerException
at LogicThread.getHandSize(GameLogic.java:22)
at LogicThread.run(GameLogic.java:16)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

the classes in question are:

```
static ObjectInputStream input;
static ObjectOutputStream output;
static Socket socket;

    public static void connectToServer(){
    try {
        System.out.println("connecting");
        socket = new Socket(ip, port);
        input = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        output = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        output.flush();
        System.out.println("connected");
        reciveData();
        logic.startLogic();
        //listenForData();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static Object reciveData(){
    try {
        Object obj = input.readObject(); - Error is on this line
        System.out.println(obj);
        return obj;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The server code for sending data:

```
    ServerSocket server;
    server = new ServerSocket(2302);
    Socket connection;
    connection = server.accept();
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

    public void sendData(Object data){
    try {
        output.writeObject(data);
        output.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am not sure what causes this because the server sends a "Connection Received" which the client receives with no issue and prints. But any call from outside the connectToServer() Method cause the error above.

Comment: We need to see the server side code too.

Comment: @EJP yea forgot it just added it

Comment: EOFException is End Of File exception. You have finished reading everything in the stream, and attempted to read from it again.

Comment: Where is sendData() called?

Comment: @KayKay it is called in a different class and sends a string to the client

Comment: @EPJ ok thanks i will try find where that happens

Comment: Is it called before the client calls receiveData() ?

Comment: @KayKay yes it is called before receive data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The peer has closed the connection. Somewhere the server is closing the accepted socket or one of its streams.

That implies that if the server has really called `sendData()` it must have thrown an exception you haven't mentioned.

Comment: i found the error one of the classes was closing the connection